# How do I get all the classes in a module?

Tags: python

How do I get all the classes in a module? For example if a module has classes A, B and C, how do I get the names of all these classes through code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import importlib, inspect

inspect.getmembers(
    importlib.import_module("your_module"),
    inspect.isclass
)
```

this will give you what you are looking for.